# Webpack style-loader, css-loader, file-loader npm install issue

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader

When I install the style-loader, css-loader, file-loader at the same time using the `npm install` command, then it successfully installs all 3 modules.

But when trying to install each of them one by one, only one (the last installed module) is left and the others are gone (I can't find the module in my `node_modules` folder).

Does anyone know why it happens?

This issue is also related to "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ..." error.

Comment: What command are you using for instalation?'

Comment: @Vikas Arora  i'm using npm install --save-dev